# System Crash when I swipe to Delete a ListView item and then Select another Item

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2019

Getting an exception when I swipe to delete or any menu item added to a list view item and then select a different item.

Changed a bunch of properties to see if I could narrow it down, but nothing seems to help.  Saw a bunch of people had an issue with `HasUnevenRows`, but changing the value does not change the behavior.

I create the View in code for the List View Items, passing in the Event Handler for Delete when it is allowed:

```
if (!(EventHandlerItemDelete == null))
{
    var deleteAction = new Xamarin.Forms.MenuItem
    {
        Text = "Delete",
        IsDestructive = true,
    };

    deleteAction.SetBinding(Xamarin.Forms.MenuItem.CommandParameterProperty, new Binding("."));
    deleteAction.Clicked += EventHandlerItemDelete;

    ContextActions.Add(deleteAction);
}

this.View = LayoutCell;
```

Expected results are not to crash:  Here is the Outer Exception:

> Outer.Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
>   Outer.Source: Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS
>   Outer.StackTrace:   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ContextScrollViewDelegate+<>c__DisplayClass25_0.b__1 (UIKit.UIGestureRecognizer recognizer, UIKit.UIGestureRecognizer r) [0x00000] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\ContextScrollViewDelegate.cs:178 
>     at UIKit.UIGestureRecognizer+_UIGestureRecognizerDelegate.ShouldRecognizeSimultaneously (UIKit.UIGestureRecognizer gestureRecognizer, UIKit.UIGestureRecognizer otherGestureRecognizer) [0x0000a] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.10.0.157/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIGestureRecognizer.g.cs:908 
>     at (wrapper managed-to-native) UIKit.UIApplication.UIApplicationMain(int,string[],intptr,intptr)
>     at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.IntPtr principal, System.IntPtr delegate) [0x00005] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.10.0.157/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:86 
>     at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x0000e] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.10.0.157/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:65 
>     at XamAppGrandLife.iOS.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00002] in C:\Development\GLH\Administration\XamAppGrandLife\XamAppGrandLife.iOS\Main.cs:15 
>   Outer.Data: System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal

Comment: Someone had a similar error in an earlier version of Xamarin.Forms.  I am using the latest version, 4.0.0.497661.

Comment: Your exception shows that the object you are trying to access is null. Try debugging your code one line at a time to check you object for null values.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  Unfortunately I do not have access to the Xamarin code where the exception occurs.  The one thing I did find is that it has to do with my list being inside a TableSection of a TableView.  If I take the ListView and display it in a StackLayout, it works fine.  I just like the flow of the TableView and how everything is displayed.